# How to make a timer based on English time

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I use daily rewards in my game, the date in "dd/MM/yyyy" format is based on `Locale.ENGLISH`

```
final Date currentDate = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

To make it more clear for the user, I want to count down the remaining time until the next reward, I also want to base the countdown on `Locale.ENGLISH`

I would like the format to be in 24h, for example if it is 12h sharp, the countdown will show 12:00:00

My current code :

```
long durationTime = 3600;

        new CountDownTimer(durationTime, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        @SuppressLint("DefaultLocale") String time = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "%02d:%02d:%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished),
                                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished)-
                                TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished)),
                                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished)-
                                TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished)));

                        final String[] hourMinSec = time.split(":");

                        timeHours.setText(hourMinSec[0]);
                        timeMinutes.setText((hourMinSec[1]));
                        timeSeconds.setText((hourMinSec[2]));
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {

            }
        }.start();
```

I need to replace the value of `long durationTime`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never use `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`. Those terrible legacy classes were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Getting the current date-time requires a time zone. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by time zone. Specify the desired/expected time zone, or ask for the JVM’s current default time zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Casablanca" ) ;
ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;
```

Apparently you want to know the amount of time until the first moment of the next day as seen in that time zone.

Do not assume the day starts at 00:00. Some dates in some zones start at another time such as 01:00. Let *java.time* determine the first moment of the day.

```
ZonedDateTime startOfTomorrow = now.toLocalDate().plusDays( 1 ).atStartOfDay( z ) ;
```

Calculate time to elapse.

```
Duration d = Duration.between( now , startOfTomorrow ) ;
```

I suggest you *not* use clock-time format to report a duration. The ambiguity makes it easy for the user to confuse a duration for a time of day.  I would build a string from the parts provided by the `Duration#to…Part` methods.

But if you insist, use the `LocalTime` class in this hack.

```
String output = LocalTime.MIN.plus( d ).toString() ;  // I recommend *against* using this format, but if you insist…
```

You said:

> I also want to base the countdown on Locale.ENGLISH

Locales have nothing to do with tracking time. Their only use in this context is for localizing text when presenting to the user.

Locales and time zones are two separate issues, orthogonal, intersecting only upon localization of presentation.

Comment: I forgot to send my message yesterday, sorry for the notification. First of all thank you very much it works very well. I plan to use this system for daily user rewards and to store dates, I am thinking of using a regional system to categorize users, so South and North America, Europe, Asia, Africa and Australia. My question, according to you, who knows this system best, should I use only one TimeZone per region? By that I mean, for Europe, I base myself on Paris time, for Australia Canberra, Africa Casablanca...

Answer (score 1):

Basically you want to calculate the difference between now and a specific date in seconds in order to display the countdown accordingly.

Based on your post, I assume the "unlocking date" of the reward is received as a string in the format `dd/MM/yyyy`.

You already have your corresponding `SimpleDateFormat`, so you can use it to parse the unlock date into a Date object:

```
String unlockDateAsString = "26/05/2022";
Date unlockDate = dateFormat.parse(unlockDateAsString);
```

The time part is initialized with 0 in that case, which is exactly what you'll need.

You can also get the current time:

```
Date now = new Date();
```

With [Date.getTime()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime()) you can fetch the milliseconds since epoch. By subtracting the future milliseconds from the present milliseconds, you get the difference which then only needs to be converted to seconds.

```
long differenceInMilliseconds = unlockDate.getTime() - now.getTime();
long differenceInSeconds = differenceInMilliseconds / 1000;
```